# Unable to set refresh rate above 60Hz on a 144Hz display on Ubuntu 22.04

Tags: gnome, graphics, performance

I am unable to set the refresh rate above 60Hz, but my display's native refresh rate is 144Hz.  The mouse and windows have a delay and a ghost effect when I move them around. It's hard to use the mouse accurately. Even the typing experience is slow. I am not sure if drivers are even installed.

I have a Ryzen 5 3600, a Radeon 5700 XT, and 32GB RAM.  The display is a [BenQ EX3203R](https://www.benq.com/en-ca/monitor/gaming/ex3203r.html) with a native resolution of 2560x1440 @ 144Hz.

Things that I tried so far:

- Set the refresh rate to 120Hz under the settings, but it reverts back to 60Hz. 144Hz is not even an option in display settings.  Setting the refresh rate to anything except 60Hz automatically reverts back to 60Hz.
- Downloaded and installed AMD drivers from their website
- Updated and upgraded all packages
- Tried to manually edit the GRUB file to add 144hz to my native resolution
- Tried with both HDMI and Displayport cables
- Tried a live session directly from the pen-drive (same issue occurs)

Downscaling the resolution from 2560x1440 to 1920x1080 fixes the refresh rate issue, but I want to be able to use the native resolution.

Here is my GRUB config and my display settings:

[image: GRUB config]

[image: System Settings Menu > Display Settings]

Comment: Yep, there is a typo, I meant 1080. And I think that is the root of the problem. 144hz is not actually appearing under settings, and when I try to use 120hz, it defaults back to 60hz. I followed this tutorial, but with no success: https://davejansen.com/add-custom-resolution-and-refresh-rate-when-using-wayland-gnome/

Comment: Thank you. I did try different cables and inputs. At the time of the screenshot, I was using a fast HDMI that does support 1440p. Right now I'm using Displayport and I updated the grub file to reflect the input change. The cable shouldn't be the issue since the same cable works fine on Windows and Mac. It's a fresh Ubuntu install. I'll try the live session and see if it works. Thanks again.

Comment: HDMI 2.0 supports up to 18Gbbps; 1440p@144hz needs 16Gbps. That's quite on the edge. Linux cannot support HDMI 2.1 due to patent issues (blame the HDMI forum for that). Make sure to use DisplayPort and that your card and monitor supports DP 1.3 or higher. You may find useful info by parsing the EDID of your monitor (see https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/bionic/man1/get-edid.1.html). Edit: You didn't post which Ubuntu and kernel version you're using.

Comment: That is interesting. But yeah, I'm currently using Displayport and both the monitor and the GPU support DP 1.4. Fresh install of the Ubuntu 22.04 (I just updated the title).

Comment: @Nmath - live session does not fix the issue, unfortunately. I can only see 60hz as an option for my native resolution.

Comment: Please read and understand page 3 of https://esupportdownload.benq.com/esupport/LCD%20MONITOR/UserManual/EX3203R/EX3203R_RF_EN_210104180503.pdf Carefully analyze the table and you'll see it describes exactly what you experieneced.

Comment: @ChanganAuto - Do you mind elaborating? This same display works fine (max refresh rate) on Windows and Mac, so I'm not sure what you mean here.

Comment: Well, the manufacturer themselves say that can't be the case, hence why I told you to check the table where it shows that for the native resolution only "PC timing" of 60Hz is available for DisplayPort or HDMI ("Video timing" at 144Hz for DisplayPort or USB-C). Think about what you're seeing in Windows as an "illusion", a marketing gimmick. This is very typical for most monitors, the very small player Spanish BenQ is no exception. Finally, 60Hz is perfectly fine, in a proper double-blind experiment you wouldn't be able to tell the difference. 60Hz is what you get in Windows 99% of the time.

Comment: Got it. I'll keep digging, but thanks for the answer though. I'm (unfortunately I guess) able to tell the difference between a 60hz and a 70hz monitor right away. And I can't just go back to anything below 120hz. That's a huge dealbreaker for me when shopping for a TV, smartphone or any device with a display, really.

Comment: @Nmath Yes, differences can be dramatic in 3D gaming but nowhere else. I'm also confused about the "PC timing" vs. "Video timing", also the 1st time seeing this distinction, but my guess is it means merely desktop drawing, mostly static, in a PC vs. pure video, perhaps gaming, and/or other devices. It may mean, in Windows (graphics driver dependent), the monitor can use the max clock in very specific situations but in typical desktop usages it defaults to 60Hz. That would explain why the usually more limited Linux drivers don't even show higher frequencies for the max resolution. (...)

Comment: (...) Many monitors don't support their max clock at the max resolution (many 4K monitors can only do 30Hz at 4K). And yes, BenQ is - correction - a small Chinese player with HQ in Taipei (Taiwan province) almost entirely dependent on their mainland OEMs. Very successful in EU with their projectors but definitely not with monitors (for years I've read Spanish press referring to BenQ as a Spanish company, hence my mistake).

Comment: @ChanganAuto - BenQ is THE monitor when it comes to e-sports and one of the best for gaming, but that is not really the point here. I contacted their support and it looks like they in fact don't support 144hz on PC. This refresh rate is only achievable on consoles, which is super lame. The PC versus Video timing thing on their manual is basically saying PC versus Console. Props to Windows and Mac I suppose(?), since they "fake" the hardware so the monitor sees them as a Console? No idea what's happening behind the scenes here.

Comment: @MoisésPio I still don't like them but you do you :) I'm glad and at the same time sad that customer support confirmed my hypotheses above which, being honest, was entirely pulled out of that place where the sun doesn't shine (but with a minimal logical thinking at its base). Now, I don't think Windows or Mac or their drivers are "faking hardware". It's much more plausible they somehow detect that mode when querying and present it but don't actually use it except maybe in the best possible scenario, i.e., parts perfectly aligned, whereas in Linux it's either limited or "truthful".

Answer (score 3):

Finally solved it!

The problem was related to the FreeSync technology. After reading the manual, I realized that depending if you have FreeSync enabled or not, the color profile and refresh rate are actually different. I found this information on [the user manual](https://esupportdownload.benq.com/esupport/LCD%20MONITOR/UserManual/EX3203R/EX3203R_UM_EN_201204181603.pdf) (page 44).

Since this was enabled, Ubuntu was (perhaps correctly?) not recognizing 144hz. Just make sure you restart your computer **after** disabling FreeSync on your monitor and updating the GRUB file with the desired resolution and refresh rate.

Thank you everyone who guided me to the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

The BenQ EX3203R, according to the [official documentation](https://esupportdownload.benq.com/esupport/LCD%20MONITOR/UserManual/EX3203R/EX3203R_RF_EN_210104180503.pdf), p. 3 table, and confirmed by the manufacturer's Customer Service does indeed support **2560x1440 @ 144Hz** but for **consoles only**.

When used with a **PC** the monitor is limited to **2560x1440 @ 60Hz**.

This is presented in the aforementioned table as "PC timing" (PC) and "Video timing" (Console).

As tested by the OP it may show the 144Hz option in Windows or Mac but it's unclear whether it's actually using it or just reporting what was queried, or whether it can actually achieve the "official unsupported" timing in specific circumstances (e.g. when triggered by a game). Users should assume and expect 60Hz anyway.